# Postman :"status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "message": "Not Found" in Java

Tags: java, postman, restful-url

I have a Java program that uses Postman. I am trying to make a post request on Postman. My code:

```java
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/v1/e")
public class EC {
    @PostMapping(path = "{document}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createDocument(@PathVariable Dtype document,@RequestBody String data){
        //code
    }
```

Below is the URL I am using to post:

http://localhost:8080/v1/e?document=E_PC

However, I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-05T02:22:03.008+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "path": "/v1/e"
}
```

Comment: You've put `{document}` as part of the path, not a query parameter. Try `POST /v1/e/E_PC`

Comment: A `create` POST operation normally doesn't have an additional path-component; it's just `POST /documents` with the appropriate contents. (You should also let Spring do the useful work for you and use `@RequestBody Document document` instead of passing a bare string.)

Comment: @Phil thanks that seems to work, just to confirm I am getting this error :Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while fopping.. that means I have reached the method, just now the error is occuring in the method?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/e")
public class EC {

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> createDocument(@RequestParam("document") String document){
      //code
  }

}
```

And your `POST REQUEST` is `http://localhost:8080/v1/e?document=E_PC`

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/v1/e/{document}")
public class EC {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createDocument(@PathVariable Dtype document,@RequestBody String data) {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.